# Rounded input buttons, absolute positioning, liquid width

Tags: html, css, rounded-corners

I realize there are lots of rounded buttons questions, but my needs are fairly specific, and this hasn't been answered elsewhere.

Here's my requirements:

- Works with absolutely positioned buttons
- Client side only techniques ( can't change HTML on server side )
- Works on input type=button and input type=submit (button element not needed)
- Fixed height, liquid width
- Supports IE7 or better

The absolute positioning + client side only makes most rounded corner techniques unusable in my opinion.

Images or no images does not matter (either way is fine). JavaScript is allowed.

EDIT: Changed question to reflect actual problem: the one HTML element I thought I needed wasn't really the requirement.

Comment: I'm confused on your requirements. You can't use JS at all? Or the JS used can't generate more than a single element? Because if you can't you're SOL on IE on both counts. All the technologies just create tiny elements to give the appearance of rounded corners in IE. In browsers that support CSS3 it can be done on a single element with no JS.  If you can use an image, just cut the image for your specific need.

Comment: EDIT: Clarified that JS is allowed. Liquid width doesn't work with static images.

Comment: I don't know of a way around the one element problem. Out of interest, why is that a requirement in this case?

Comment: The inputs are being absolutely positioned (out of my control - it's similar to an emulator), and I don't have the ability to modify the source coming in. It might be possible to dynamically create the wrappers and position them, but I believe it would be slow and a nightmare to get working cross-browsers.  Might be my next question though:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using multiple backgrounds for the buttons.

CSS3 multiple backgrounds for browsers that could handle that, and in IE I used the DXTransform filter to add a second image (see [here](http://cookbooks.adobe.com/post_Cross_Browser_Multi_background_images__including_I-16839.html)).  The actual technique used was a pretty standard sliding door style setup, with some changes to account for the fact that you couldn't position the second image in IE other than at the top left.

For FF 3.5 and lower I used border-radius, since multiple backgrounds only came in 3.6.

Hover/active images worked fine, and it's all in CSS, which was a bonus.

Answer (score 3):

It's not possible for IE. That's why you can't find it anywhere else. The only thing you could do is use a static background image, but that will stretch for different widths.

Comment: This is correct. It is possible to create a static background, but as he said if it is resized it will cause stretching and pixelation (very ugly). You can do it with javascript, but generally it will create extra elements for you.

Answer (score 0):

Since javascript is allowed (based on one of your comments), I don't see how it would be a big performance hit to:

1. wrap the `input` elements with `div`
2. take the positioning properties of the `input` and copy them to the `div` wrapper
3. remove the positioning off the `input` using an inline `position: static`
4. add other elements or styles to get your rounded corners. Being fixed height, then for everything other than IE7, some css like this should work (assumes fixed height of 20px, rounded end images that are 10px wide by 20px high):

Css:

```
div.inputWrap:before, 
div.inputWrap:after {content: ' '; display: inline-block; height: 20px; width: 10px; background: url(/yourRoundedLeftEndImg.png) top left no-repeat;}

div.inputWrap:after {background: url(yourRoundedRightEndImg.png);}
```

Assuming your javascript gives you this html:

```
<div class="inputWrap"><input /></div>
```

You will need to style the input to get rid of borders, and such (I also found that my test in Firefox required me to set `vertical-align: top`, but not sure if that is necessary. For IE6-7, you would actually have to add extra div's before and after the `input` since they do not recognize the `:before` and `:after` pseudo-classes.

Comment: I had seen the :before/:after idea before, but I wasn't sure how that would interact with the absolute positioning. I guess I'll change the question title because that's really the requirement, not the one element item.  
I'll test this idea out though.

Comment: As long as you have the wrapper take on the same absolute positioning as what the input originally had, you should not have any issues.

Comment: This technique worked, but there were some other complications with the code I was working with that made it quite annoying the get right (setting widths/heights and cross-browser padding issues, for one).  

My answer has a CSS only solution that I found much simpler and rendered much faster.